# Kubernetes nginx-ingress load balancer external IP pending

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ingress

In my Kubernetes cluster I want to bind a nginx load balancer to the external IP of a node. However, the external IP is always shown as "pending".

The cluster runs on two root-servers using weave.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Using the "externalIPs" array works but is not what I want, as the IPs are not managed by Kubernetes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like additional software is needed to create a resource of kind "LoadBalancer" if run on bare metal: https://metallb.universe.tf/